# Is ADF Copy Activity safe to use with storage account key and a remote IR

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

If an AzureBlobStorage Linked Service using a storage account key for authentication is used as either a sink or a source in a Copy Activity, will ADF transmit the storage account key over to the Integration Runtime, or will it generate an SAS token limited to the target container?

In other words, is there a risk that someone with access to the server running the Integration Runtime will be able to acquire the storage account key?

Answer (score 1):

If you use self-hosted integration runtime (SHIR), and need access to outer services, SHIR will need the credentials for those services.

You have 2 options:

1. Save the account key in Azure key vault, and SHIR will only take it at runtime
2. Save the account key on SHIR locally. The account key will be encrypted, and store on the SHIR machine.

Documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#credentials-store

Comment: The Linked Service is configured to retrieve the key from a Key Vault. If I'm reading that linked document right, it seems that in either case, the Storage Account Key is transmitted to the SHIR and is at risk of being leaked if the IR host is compromised. Thus SAS authentication is safer to use in this case.